# What area can this question be categorized into?

Tags: problem-solving

In a game of 12 players that lasts for exactly 75 minutes there are 6 reserves who alternate
equally with starting players. It means that all players, including reserves, are in the game for
exactly the same amount of time.
How long is this?

5 people entered a train carriage with only 2 seats not occupied. The 5 people took in turn so each person had equal time to sit. if the total journey took 1 hour 10 minutes, how long did each person have the seat for?

These questions are very similar have similar working techniques. I would like to know what you call these types of question and how you work it out?

Answer (score 0):

I think in puzzle category. You can solve these questions by an equation 
$$\frac{x}{y}\cdot z,$$
where $z$ is your time, $x$ is number of "places" and $y$ is the number of pepole.

For example, in your first question,
$$x=12,\quad y=18,\quad z=75.$$

Comment: Can you be more specific please? :)